# Date range from today's date ordered by DD/MM/YYYY for the next week

Tags: php, mysql, date, sql-order-by

My table column titled "property_appointment" is formatted as DD/MM/YYYY and it is too far gone to change to a default date and time setting due to the amount of data that exists.

What I am having trouble with is getting a range of appointments (sorted by the date) to show from today's date going forward, i.e. the query should show the next 6 appointments in the system from today's date. Currently it is showing appointments scheduled for next year that are booked, which isn't helpful when I want to see a small forecast for the upcoming week, as it is sorting the dates by descending order. It hasn't been instructed to show appointments from today onwards and I have tried many things but I still cannot figure this out.

I know the date format is making this very difficult to achieve, but is there a workaround for my current date format to achieve the above? Any help is much appreciated!

```
if($properties = $db->prepare("
SELECT id
     , property_address_line_1
     , property_appointment
     , property_appointment_type 
  FROM users 
  JOIN properties 
    ON id = property_user_id 
 WHERE id = ? 
 ORDER 
    BY STR_TO_DATE(property_appointment,'%d/%m/%Y') DESC 
 LIMIT 6
 "))
```

Comment: Why is it to far gone? Make a new column, set it correctly, run an update.

Comment: Store dates as dates. This is a 'no-brainer'.

Comment: What is wrong with `STR_TO_DATE`?

Comment: There are 1406 properties in the database and running an update to copy the date and change the format is above my skill level.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT id
     , property_address_line_1
     , property_appointment
     , property_appointment_type 
  FROM users 
  JOIN properties 
    ON id = property_user_id 
 WHERE id = ? 
   AND STR_TO_DATE(property_appointment,'%d/%m/%Y')  > CURDATE()
 ORDER BY STR_TO_DATE(property_appointment,'%d/%m/%Y') 
 LIMIT 6
```